# Google Fit insert TYPE_WORKOUT_EXERCISE in Android

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I want to add my app's workouts in google fit. So i tried with the curls workout for now as in the official example ... my code is:

```
// Create a data source
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
                .setAppPackageName(this)
                .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_WORKOUT_EXERCISE)
                .setName(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
                .build();

//        // Create a data set
        DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);
        DataPoint curls = DataPoint.create(dataSource);
        curls.setTimestamp(now.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        curls.getValue(Field.FIELD_EXERCISE).setString(WorkoutExercises.BICEP_CURL);
        curls.getValue(Field.FIELD_DURATION).setInt(30000);
        curls.getValue(Field.FIELD_REPETITIONS).setInt(10);
        curls.getValue(Field.FIELD_RESISTANCE_TYPE).setInt(Field.RESISTANCE_TYPE_DUMBBELL);
        curls.getValue(Field.FIELD_RESISTANCE).setFloat(20.0f);
        dataSet.add(curls);

Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mClient, dataSet)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Data insert was successful!");
                        } else {
                            // The deletion will fail if the requesting app tries to delete data
                            // that it did not insert.
                            Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem inserting the dataset.");
                            //TODO store dataset to send it later or make this as a service
                        }
                    }
                });
```

The problem is that the insert method logs a success but i see no data being added in Google Fit. I tried with other types of workout, like Planks to the same result. However adding steps count works, as in the official insert in history example so i guess i'm missing something related to the type workout. Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

As much as I know Google fit doesn't Show the workout exercises. If you wanted to show it you show add an activity to google fit In TYPE_Activity_SAMPLE or TYPE _ACTIVITY_SEGMENT data type . WorkoutExercise is diffrent class For adding only Exercises . If you need Adding exercise which are define under FitnessActivities .You should use it and it will also show in google fit app with your application name ..

```
public void insertFitnessActivity(ExerciseBean bean) {

    /*
     * Distance Data source
     */ 
    DataSource distance = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName(context)
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW).build();
    DataSet distanceDataSet = DataSet.create(distance);
    DataPoint distanceDataPoint = DataPoint.create(distance)
            .setTimeInterval(bean.getStartTime(), bean.getEndTime(),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    distanceDataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_DISTANCE).setFloat((float) bean.getEx_distance());
    distanceDataSet.add(distanceDataPoint);
    com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status distanceInsertStatus = Fitness.HistoryApi
            .insertData(fitnessClient, distanceDataSet).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    /*
     * Steps Data source
     */
    DataSource steps = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName("package")
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW).build();
    DataSet stepsDataSet = DataSet.create(steps);
    DataPoint stepsDataPoint = DataPoint.create(steps).setTimeInterval(
            bean.getStartTime(), bean.getEndTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    stepsDataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).setInt(bean.getSteps());
    stepsDataSet.add(stepsDataPoint);
    com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status statusInsert = Fitness.HistoryApi
            .insertData(fitnessClient, stepsDataSet).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    /*
     * Calory Data source
     */
    DataSource calory = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName("package")
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW).build();
    DataSet calDataSet = DataSet.create(calory);
    DataPoint calDataPoint = DataPoint.create(calory).setTimeInterval(
            bean.getStartTime(), bean.getEndTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    // calDataPoint.setFloatValues((float)bean.getEx_calories());
    calDataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_CALORIES).setFloat(
            (float) bean.getEx_calories());
    calDataSet.add(calDataPoint);

    com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status insertStatus = Fitness.HistoryApi
            .insertData(fitnessClient, calDataSet).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    /*
     * Activity data source
     */
    DataSource acSource = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName(context)
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW).build();
    DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(acSource);
    DataPoint dataPoint = DataPoint.create(acSource).setTimeInterval(
            bean.getStartTime(), bean.getEndTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_ACTIVITY).setActivity(bean.getEx_Name());
    dataSet.add(dataPoint);

    com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status status = Fitness.HistoryApi
            .insertData(fitnessClient, dataSet).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

Comment: how to add calories to Activity data source?